# How to correct the render output of my reactjs TreeGraph component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graph, tree

I'm having issues with getting my TreeGraph to render properly.

### Issues:

1. Lines go to the wrong location
2. Circles Render on top of each other
3. Spacing is wrong

Is there perhaps a free open source chart/tree library which will allow me to do this on a canvas, and allow me to make each circle clickable

Example Output (tree listed below)

[image]

## Code and Samples

#### Tree Type

```js
export default class Tree {
    details:any = {};
    children:Tree[] = [];

    constructor(_details:any, _children:Tree[]){
        this.details = _details;
        this.children = _children;
    }
}
```

#### Tree Data

```js
let data = new Tree(
        { id: "XXXXXX1", name: "A", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("A")}},
        [
            new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX2", name: "B", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("B")}}, [
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX4", name: "D", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("D")}}, [])
            ]),
            new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX3", name: "C", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("C")}}, [
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX5", name: "E", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("E")}}, []),
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX6", name: "F", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("F")}}, []),
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX7", name: "G", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("G")}}, [])
            ]),
            new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX8", name: "H", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("H")}}, [
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXXX9", name: "I", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("I")}}, []),
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXX10", name: "J", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("J")}}, []),
                new Tree({ id: "XXXXX11", name: "K", onClick: ()=>{ console.log("K")}}, [])
            ]),
        ]
    );
```

#### Renderer Functional Component (ReactJS)

```js
export default function TreeRenderer(props:any){
    // Props
    const { width, height, data, styleOverrides } = props;
    // States
    const [ canvasID, setCanvasID ] = useState<string>("");
    const canvasRef = useRef<any>(null);
    // Functions
    function getTreeWidth(root: Tree): number {
        const queue: Tree[] = [root];
        let maxWidth = 0;
        while (queue.length > 0) {
          const levelSize = queue.length;
          // Update the maximum width if the current level is wider
          maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, levelSize);
          for (let i = 0; i < levelSize; i++) {
            const node = queue.shift()!; // Non-null assertion for simplicity
            // Enqueue the children for the next level
            if (node.children) {
              queue.push(...node.children);
            }
          }
        }
        return maxWidth;
      }
    function getMaxChildrenCount(node: Tree): number {
        if (!node.children || node.children.length === 0) {
          return 0;
        }      
        let maxChildrenCount = node.children.length;
        for (const child of node.children) {
          const childMaxChildrenCount = getMaxChildrenCount(child);
          if (childMaxChildrenCount > maxChildrenCount) {
            maxChildrenCount = childMaxChildrenCount;
          }
        }      
        return maxChildrenCount;
      }
      // Handles Drawing the lines, and then returns the circles (just doing it like this so the lines are drawn under the circles)
      const drawParentAndChild = (
        context: any,
        parent: Tree,
        depth: number,
        sibling: number,
        parentX: number,
        parentY: number
      ): any[] => {
        let circles: any[] = [];
        let radius = 18;
        let basePaddingY = 18;
        let basePaddingX = 18;
      
        // Adjust spacing based on depth
        let paddingY = basePaddingY;// + depth * 10;
        let paddingX = basePaddingX;// + depth * 10;
      
        let y = depth * (2 * radius + paddingY) + paddingY;
        let x = sibling * (2 * radius + paddingX) + paddingX;
        let centerX = x + radius;
        let centerY = y + radius;
      
        // Draw Line to Parent
        if (depth >= 1) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
          context.lineTo(parentX, parentY);
          context.strokeStyle = '#1E1E1E';
          context.stroke();
          context.closePath();
        }
      
        // various stuff
        let fillColor = '';
        if (depth === 0 && sibling === 0) {
          fillColor = '#1E1E1E';
        } else if (parent.details.isActive ?? false) {
          fillColor = 'red';
        } else {
          fillColor = 'green';
        }
      
        // reusable font style
        const fontFamily = 'Poppins, sans-serif';
        const fontSize = 20;
        const fontWeight = 'bold';
      
        circles.push({
          a: centerX,
          b: centerY,
          c: radius,
          d: 0,
          e: 2 * Math.PI,
          f: false,
          g: fillColor,
          h: `${fontWeight} ${fontSize}px ${fontFamily}`,
          i: '#FFFFFF',
          j: parent.details.name,
          k: x + radius / 2 + 2,
          l: y + radius + 8,
        });
      
        // Draw Children into Array (only draw the lines)
        for (let i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
          let ret = drawParentAndChild(context, parent.children[i], depth + 1, sibling + i, centerX, centerY);
          circles.push(...(ret as any[]));
        }
      
        return circles;
      };
    // Effects
    useEffect(()=>{
        // if no data, don't render
        if(!data) return;
        // Acquire Canvas
        let canvas = canvasRef ? canvasRef.current : document.getElementById(canvasID);
        // Get Width and Height of Tree
        let tWidth = getTreeWidth(data);
        let tHeight = getMaxChildrenCount(data);
        // Calculate Sizes
        let maxWidth = tWidth;
        let maxHeight = tHeight;
        // Setup Canvas
        canvas.width = maxWidth * 2024;
        canvas.height = maxHeight * 2024;
        // Get Canvas Context
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // Clear Canvas
        context.fillStyle = '#FFF';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);
        // Generate Tree Lines and return circles to draw
        let circlesAndText = drawParentAndChild(context, data, 0, 0, 18, 18);
        for(let circle of circlesAndText){
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(circle['a'], circle['b'], circle['c'], circle['d'], circle['e'], circle['f']);
            context.fillStyle = circle['g'];
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.strokeStyle = '#1E1E1E';
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
            context.font = circle['h'];
            context.fillStyle = circle['i'];
            context.fillText(circle['j'], circle['k'], circle['l']);
        }
        // Loop through
        // TODO: Go through each circle here and create a click handler, based on the circle['a'] and circle['b']
    }, [data]);
    // Render
    return <canvas className='tree-renderer-element' ref={canvasRef} style={styleOverrides} id={canvasID} width={0} height={0}></canvas>
}
```